# Flutter SetState not update Text

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, setstate

I have a page with has a Text which should show the text that I introduce in a `TextEditingController`. I paste only the important code, if needed more tell me please:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: _buildBar(context),
            body: Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                ),
                buildTitle(),
              ],
            )))),
        onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context));
...
  }
```

The method buildTitle() is:

```
Widget buildTitle() {
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        name == null ? "" : name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () {
          changeName();
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ...
]);
```

}

And changeName() is:

```
void changeName() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Name'),
              content: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Name of product",
                  errorText: incorrectName
                      ? 'The name could not be empty'
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_textController.text.length == 0) {
                      setState(() {
                        _textController.text.length == 0
                            ? incorrectName = true
                            : incorrectName = false;
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        incorrectName = false;
                        name = _textController.text;
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

At first, name is empty so only appears the edit button, but when I click on Ok the Text doesn`t change but I have anothers methods with SetState that when I click then the name appears.

Why isn't the name updated with SetState in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `changeName()` return type:

```
Future<String> changeName() {
    showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Name'),
              content: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                controller: _textController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Name of product",
                  errorText: incorrectName
                      ? 'The name could not be empty'
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_textController.text.length == 0) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(_textController.text);
                    }
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(null);
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
        });
  }
```

in Your `buildTitle()`:

```
Widget buildTitle() {
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        name == null ? "" : name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () async {
          name = await changeName();
          setState((){});
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ...
]);
```

Comment: Then, how can I controll that user doesn't enter text in textfield and show error? @LgFranco

Comment: Put the controller as parameter too.

Comment: I don`t know what do you means, could you explain or put a example please?

Comment: It doesn't work, this never update the Text. Moreover, this code doesn't show error when user press OK with `textController.text.length == 0` @LgFranco